# UISearchBar accepts only one word for searching youTube videos

Tags: objective-c, json, youtube, youtube-api

I have an app that basically search youTube videos.
This all youTube search and the result videos are in one view controller.

Now, everything works fine and i do get the wanted videos (using JSON) displayed on my view using this API: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=%@"

The problems are:
1.  UISearchBar accepts only one word to search with. if i put on the search bar two or   more words, the app crashes. (if i don't want that the two words will make my app crash,
then i need to write on the searchBar, i.e "new%20songs" instead of "new songs").
so the question for here is: do i need to detect every space on the seachBar.text and replace it with "%20"? 
or there is something more appropriate for that..?

another thing: language- my UISearchBar accepts only english! if i put another language on it-CRASH!

Do anyone have an explanation? i tried to change some of the API rules, but unsuccessfully.

EDIT: i'm not leaving here code, because i don't think it's the problem. the code works fine.. i think it's more like API problem, but of course, i'll post some code if needed.

Thanks to all !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the correct URL string you need to use [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) method. So all spaces and characters (other than English) will be replaced by special codes (eg space will be replaced %20, etc.). Example:

```
    NSString *searchStr = @"string with space";
    NSString *youtubeURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=%@", searchStr];
    NSString *URLString = [youtubeURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```